# Binding collection of viewmodel to tabcontrol with datatemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding, tabcontrol, infragistics

I am facing problem with tab control binding to collection of view models similar [as in this post](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/37015/400076.aspx)

```
<Window.Resources>
  <ViewModel:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel" />
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Foo1}">
    <local:UserControl1 />
  </DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Foo2}">
    <local:UserControl2 />
  </DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Foo3}">
    <local:UserControl3 />
  </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<igDock:XamDockManager x:Name="dm">
  <igDock:XamDockManager.Panes>
    <igDock:SplitPane>
      <igDock:ContentPane>
        <ContentControl>
          <local:Foo />
        </ContentControl>
      </igDock:ContentPane>
    </igDock:SplitPane>
  </igDock:XamDockManager.Panes>
</igDock:XamDockManager>
<DockPanel>
  <igDock:XamDockManager x:Name="dockManager">
    <igDock:TabGroupPane DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MainViewModel}"
                         SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex}">
      <igExtensions:ContentPaneFactory.PaneFactory>
        <igExtensions:ContentPaneFactory ItemsSource="{Binding TabCollection}"
                                         HeaderPath="Title"
                                         ContentPath="." />
      </igExtensions:ContentPaneFactory.PaneFactory>
    </igDock:TabGroupPane>
  </igDock:XamDockManager>
</DockPanel>
```

But as mentioned in the above article, i see that the viewmodel are getting constructed twice. First in MainViewModel when I try to populate the observable tab collection and once when I try to navigate to the tabitem.

How can I avoid this?.

Comment: The link that you included results in a 404 response.  What do you mean by the viewmodel is getting constructed twice?  Can you show the relevant logic from the ViewModels as well?

Comment: Fixed the link. Can you please try again?.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this question is already answered in the Infragistics's forum thread that you have linked.

If you have further questions I can suggest you ask them in the IG forums, since you can get an answer from an IG expert.